# Can anyone help me link my Accordian and Jquery css to a normal page in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

When trying to link an accordion that I have made and some jquery css to a normal view page in codeigniter, I have linked them through the right folders but it doesn't seem to know where it is can anyone help?

The jquery link is long because it runs through a few folders.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url()."css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css";?> type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url()."css/my_accordion.js";?>"</script>
```

Accordion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("ready to do some jquery");
// $( "p" ).hide(); hide paragraphs
//$( "h2").hide(); // h2 hide
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
      console.log("you clicked a paragraph!");
      $( "p" ).hide(500);

      if (!$(this).hasClass("activeHeading")){ 


                  $(".activeHeading").next().slideUp(1000);
                  $(".activeHeading").removeClass("activeHeading");


                  $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
                  $(this).addClass("activeHeading");
      } //end of if
  }); //end of click
}); //end of document
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra forward slash before "css". See below:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url()."/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/dark-hive
/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css";?> type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url()."/css/my_accordion.js";?>"</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your css directory is within your application folder then CodeIgniter's rewrite rules may be preventing access to the files.

Try adding the following line in your .htaccess file in the root of the code igniter app.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(application/css)
```

So the first few lines should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(application/css)
```